# Backend terminated or disconnected. Use 'Stop/Restart' to restart on Raspberrry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, ocr, thonny

I'm running an Optical Character Reading program on my raspberry pi 3 B+, after getting everything running, i decided to transfer to raspberry pi zero but start receiving "Backend terminated or disconnected. Use 'Stop/Restart' to restart" on running it. when i tried to run the code form the terminal, i received "Illegal Instruction"

Answer (score 0):

First disconnect from the secondary power, that is, if it is within a circuit. Ensure that its only USB that is supplying power (of course when editing a code on your editor), this is how I solved similar problem on my rasberry pico pi.